# JSON to R data.frame

Tags: json, r, rjson

I have a problem using `rjson` package to convert JSON to R `data.frame`.

I started with:

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "btcusd.txt"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

`btcusd.txt` file contains the following:

```
{"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":true,"Data":
        [{"time":1510650000,"close":6488.28,"high":6618.69,"low":6482.22,"open":6492.35,"volumefrom":9422.44,"volumeto":61626698.63},
        {"time":1510671600,"close":6541,"high":6592.05,"low":6487.35,"open":6549.1,"volumefrom":12618.61,"volumeto":82634018.7},],
        "TimeTo":1511298000,"TimeFrom":1510574400,"FirstValueInArray":true,"ConversionType":{"type":"direct","conversionSymbol":""}}
```

Can anyone help me to make it into a data.frame?

Comment: I get an error with jsonlite::fromJSON:  `Error: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
          18.61,"volumeto":82634018.7},], "TimeTo":1511298000,"TimeFro
                     (right here) ------^`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `jsonlite` package.

Based on what you have I'd try this:

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)

mydata <- fromJSON("btcusd.txt")
```

But, I inspected your data and it's messy. Can you provide some additional information? if that comes from an API maybe it's easier to read the XML version instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here's the API I was trying to use: 

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=3&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma in your JSON input.  If you remove the comma it works OK:

```
json_txt <- '{
    "Response": "Success",
    "Type": 100,
    "Aggregated": true,
    "Data": [{
            "time": 1510650000,
            "close": 6488.28,
            "high": 6618.69,
            "low": 6482.22,
            "open": 6492.35,
            "volumefrom": 9422.44,
            "volumeto": 61626698.63
    }, {
            "time": 1510671600,
            "close": 6541,
            "high": 6592.05,
            "low": 6487.35,
            "open": 6549.1,
            "volumefrom": 12618.61,
            "volumeto": 82634018.7
    }], 
    "TimeTo": 1511298000,
    "TimeFrom": 1510574400,
    "FirstValueInArray": true,
    "ConversionType": {
            "type": "direct",
            "conversionSymbol": ""
    }   
}'  
data.frame(fromJSON(json_txt))
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives me a 2 rows data.frame, where column names are "Response", "Type", "Aggregated" and so on. 

When I remove parts containing them from the JSON, I get a 2 rows data frame, where column names are (as desired): 
"time", "close", "high", "low", "open", "volumefrom", 
"volumeto". 



The problem is that it works only for one element of time series and I need to do this for hundreds of elements.